# Samsung "My Files" Downloads folder corrupted on non-rooted phone

Tags: internal-storage, samsung-galaxy-note-9

On my Note 9 unrooted phone, for whatever reason, if I delete files from the **"Downloads"** section of the My Files app, these files (or references to them) aren't completely removed.  A residual "0 byte" file with no name and a time date stamp of "December 31, 1969 4:00pm" is leftover. Also, these residual files can't be moved or deleted.

This ***Downloads*** section seems to have a relation to the `/emulated/0/Download/` folder... although, not the same thing. If I delete the *"Download"* folder, the *"Downloads"* section remains unaffected.

In the Windows OS world, I would just run `chkdsk` to quickly fix the corrupted file indexes on the file system. However, I'm not sure what the equivalent is for an unrooted Android OS.

Things I've tried:

1. Wipe the cache partition
2. Delete the /emulated/o/download folder and recreating it again.
3. Force Stopping the My Files app, clear cache, clear data.  This is supposed to be similar to clearing the app cache for 'Media Storage' app on non-Samsung Android devices

I **REALLY** don't want to factory reset my phone, considering how much time I spent configuring all my applications... unless I have absolutely no choice (and know for sure it would fix this issue).  This issue is completely over my head.  I'm hoping an Android expert will know what to do in this case without having to do a factory reset.  **Maybe, I can do something via ADB shell?**

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an app named **Media storage** in Android OS that stores the database of files and folders in the storage of your device. Looks like there is some problem with this app, so you need to *clear it's data and cache.*

To do that, go to ***System settings->Apps***, click on the ***menu button (3 dots)*** then click on ***Show system***. Then, in the apps list, you can find an app named **Media storage**. Click on it and clear it's data and cache. See this screenshot :
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much.  However, I dont have that app listed on my phone's apps:  http://oucvlq.dm.files.1drv.com/y4pxoa1SpKM_c921ZWAOD6DNrGaTwiq-LC-bcg1DBufWvcvAN6Oe6Npif88RmUP8CtsaLoHIsTFscL69LZuFeLfDeVQddFK8oUtLFo0yt0yyzwC-erNcSZxOhhcUxTjMNejauHUOabKGFdgwC7Exhe2Z4Piw8IrbItHJEn6cPLLTbVVBbMjVldNdydHw4ZSedUXdoMG3YFbUbSYZnZhr9Odqw9Im7JYJnqc-jRaQXZZ2N4

Comment: Could I download it, install it, and then do it?  Would it be compatible with my Samsung Note 9 with Android Pie 9?  https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/media-storage/media-storage-9-2-release/media-storage-9-2-android-apk-download/

Comment: Samsung's version of "Media Storage" IS the "My Files" app.  Unfortunately, deleting the app cache and app data for this app doesn't resolve the issue.  There are still strange files in the Downloads area.  In fact, sometimes the My Files app itself crashes if I go into the Downloads area.

Comment: **Media storage** is a system app, so it is pre-installed in the OS, you can't download it.

Comment: After clearing it's data and cache, have you rebooted your phone?

Comment: Have you tried any *third-party* **file manager** app?

Comment: Yes.  I've rebooted my phone after clearing the app cache and app data for the "My Files" app (Samsung's replacement for Media Storage).  Not sure what else to try.

Comment: According to me, Media storage app is present in every version of Android. The link which you provided me about your screenshot, I have understood that you haven't clicked on Show system option. Tap on the 3 dots icon at the top right part of the screen and click on **Show system**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92059/discussion-between-mkanet-and-puspam-adak).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and somehow managed to delete the 0b file in my download folder (dated 1970 for some reason?) using a cleaning app called "SD maid".